# Replication and Partitioning Tables in GemfireXD?

Tags: in-memory-database, hana, gemfire

1. How can we decide a particular table need to replicate/Partitioning ?
2. Use of Replication tables in *GemfireXD* data base design ?

All explanations are the most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table should be REPLICATE in following scenario

1. If it is a `Code table`. *A code table is a list of closely related items, each of which has minimal substructure.*
2. If it is a small table in size
3. If application requires query with joins involving very large and small tables, then smaller tables must be REPLICATED

Please go through the following links:
http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#data_management/replication-deciding.html

http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#data_management/partitioning.html#concept_08031D9C1AEA48F1B4B021CA1BE3ABF5